# scipy is not optimizing and returns “Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss”

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, minimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to find the best place to aim in the darts when you can throw a dart with some normal distribution. For that, I have a function (`exp_val`), that chooses a point on it, count expected value of 1000 throws (I know parameters of distribution), and returns the expected value.

```
def exp_val(arg):
x = arg[0]
y = arg[1]

arr_x = create_data_axe(x, sigma_x)
arr_y = create_data_axe(y, sigma_y)

exp_val = 0

for i in range(len(arr_x)):
    exp_val += how_much(arr_x[i], arr_y[i])

exp_val /= len(arr_x)
print(exp_val)
return exp_val
```

`how_much` is just a function, that returns points, where you hit the darts field.

```
def how_much(x, y):
r = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
alpha = np.arctan(float(y)/float(x))*180/np.pi
#print(r, alpha)

if r > 17.0:
    return 0

if r < 0.635:
    return -50

if r >= 0.635 and r < 1.59:
    return -25

score = 0
if alpha >= -90 and alpha < -81:
    if x > 0:
        score = 3
    else:
        score = 20
    
if alpha >= -81 and alpha < -63:
    if x > 0:
        score = 17
    else:
        score = 5

if alpha >= -63 and alpha < -45:
    if x > 0:
        score = 2
    else:
        score = 12

if alpha >= -45 and alpha < -27:
    if x > 0:
        score = 15
    else:
        score = 9

if alpha >= -27 and alpha < -9:
    if x > 0:
        score = 10
    else:
        score = 14

if alpha >= -9 and alpha < 9:
    if x > 0:
        score = 6
    else:
        score = 11

if alpha >= 9 and alpha < 27:
    if x > 0:
        score = 13
    else:
        score = 8

if alpha >= 27 and alpha < 45:
    if x > 0:
        score = 4
    else:
        score = 16

if alpha >= 45 and alpha < 63:
    if x > 0:
        score = 18
    else:
        score = 7

if alpha >= 63 and alpha < 81:
    if x > 0:
        score = 1
    else:
        score = 19

if alpha >= 81 and alpha < 90:
    if x > 0:
        score = 20
    else:
        score = 3

return -score
```

I am trying to find the minimum of this function, using the scipy.optimize.minimize, but it only returns `'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss'` or `'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'` errors :(

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
x0 = [1, 2]
res = minimize(exp_val, x0, method='CG')

    fun: -14.187
     jac: array([  2952790.01599991, -31541166.08000004])
 message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
    nfev: 104
     nit: 1
    njev: 23
  status: 2
 success: False
       x: array([0.99999983, 1.99999985])
```

(I've tried different methods, but all doesn't work). As I guess, the problem is in the `exp_val` function, because it has big areas with the same return value (case when you hit the concrete sector). But I am not sure and I don't know how to fix this. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Most methods (including CG) expect smooth functions. Your function is not smooth. So you are cheating, and the solver reacts accordingly.